# Backup Source (non source control)?

Tags: backup

I back up my code with svn. I have project files in there however i ignore selected things. I also ignore jpg, ogg, etc.

Right now i would like to backup everything. However the zip result is >1gb (i have a lot of code). I know i can cut down the filesize by 60%+

Is there an app i can use which will backup everything except the bin and obj folders? perhaps keep ogg, json, jpg files but ignore .svn or .pdb files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

roboocopy windows command line since vista. Can exclude files and folders with a separate exclude pattern.  Has /MIR which delete files that have been deleted from source dir, copy updated files and leave alone existing unchanged files. Can copy permissions as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use good old `tar` with `-j` for `bzip2` compression and `-X` with a file containing patterns to exclude.

`man tar`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add your jpg/ogg files to svn as well? Don't you need them to build?

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is to store everything in svn that can't be easily recreated or downloaded.  So any images would go in there, along with documentation, html, etc., but third party libraries or jars would not.  Basically, you should be able to check out the source on a new machine, install any dependencies, and build.   If you can't do this, at some point you will run into trouble.